# Setting Session on Specific Event Calls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session

I have an MVC application and a custom class called `AuthorisationFilter` which has a .NET interface of `IAuthorizationFilter`, this has an `OnAuthorization` method which gets called when I click around my site, at that point I go about validating the security access of the user (which works), but I don't want to do this all the time as it is time consuming.

In this I'm trying to use the `Session` to store a temporary piece of login information (this is an internal application by the way), but I can't get it working as I'd expect. I can't just use an `HttpContext` so end up constantly creating a new instance of `HttpContextBase`, which I assume is then clearing out the Session.  My code is as follows:

```
    internal void SetSecurityLevel(int token)
    {
        HttpContextBase _cBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        _cBase.Session["SecurityRights"] = token;
    }

    internal int GetSecurityLevel()
    {
        HttpContextBase _cBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        if (_cBase.Session["SecurityRights"] == null)
        {
            SetSecurityLevel(-1);
        }
        return (int)_cBase.Session["SecurityRights"];
    }
```

Please note this is only part of the code, SetSecurityLevel is set to the correct value by a separate method call which is not shown

Anyway what I'm really wanting to do is have the session set in this class and have it persisted.  I tried a few different ways, including setting the context when the class is initialised, but I end up with a NullReference on the `.Session` object in GetSecurityLevel

```
    private HttpContextBase _cBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
    public AuthorisationFilter()
    {
        _cBase = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);

    }
```

Is there a way I can do this within the class?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you can't set in the constructor but you can in `OnActionExecuting` when the context is available

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
{
     _session =  = filterContext.HttpContext.Session;
```

I would wonder a little why you're setting this security level in the filter and not just doing it directly from where it's needed.

Comment: I'm using that because, unfortunately for me, its part of a legacy system which already does all of the work there.  I don't have time to refactor it out at the moment.  I tried the suggestion above but it doesn't work for me, I get: `Cannot convert source type 'System.Web.HttpSessionStateBase' to target type 'System.Web.HttpContextBase'`